# How do I return the first non-blank cell in a row looking in non-contiguous columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

First time poster here so go easy on me. I've searched for several hours now and tried various things but I can't seem to come up with something that will work. I'm sure the answer is relatively simple, but I just haven't had that "ah, ha" moment yet.

I'm trying to look in a row within a range and return the first non-blank value while only looking in certain columns. For instance:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pKsx.png)

In each row labeled ID, in column B I want to find the first non-blank value in the range that would consist of columns H, K, and N. And same for columns C and D looking in each of their respective ranges from the RH columns. I will also be adding in new sets of releases (i.e. "Release 4", "Release 5", etc) which may or may not have a value for each of the 3 rev's so, as I insert columns to the left of F, I need the lookup range to expand as the values get pushed to the right. I think I could do this with VBA, but I really need to do it with a formula as I'm trying to keep my sheet clean of macros.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am stuck :(

Comment: Print screen of data would be more helpful to understand what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if the Rev 1 columns are consecutive. Suppose that your colums are ordered Like this:

Rev 1, Rev 1, Rev 1, Rev 2, Rev 2, Rev 2, Rev 3, Rev 3, Rev 3

With columns changed like this, match formula will calculate the non-blank cell's location. And then with address formula we convert this location into A1 cell style which then converted to the name of the Release with the Indirect formula.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;MATCH(FALSE;ISBLANK(H3:J3);0)+7))
```

+7 is is for the location of the first column which is H

This is an array formula. Make sure to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination

Comment: Yeah, that would be easier, but it doesn't follow the intent of the sheet. Each individual "Rev" is tied to a particular "Release".

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get the answer on another forum. Wanted to post a link in case anyone else comes looking.

[Link](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1297364-how-do-i-return-the-first-non-blank-cell-in-a-row-looking-in-non-contiguous-columns.html#post5234070)